# EF Core One-To-Many with optional principal key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get EF Core 2 Working on an existing database where there's no foreign keys specified, and "foreign keys" and principal keys keys can be null.

Using this property mapping on `Foo`:

```
e.HasOne(x => x.User)
 .WithMany()
 .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.SID)
 .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
```

Where both principal key and foreign key type is `int?`, because both `User` and `User.SID` is allowed to be `null`.

The wierd thing here is of course that `User.SID` is allowed to be `null`, but unfortunately I have no option of correcting that.

EF returns this exception when querying the collection:

> SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>
> InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'User.Id'. The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' but the actual value was null.

Is there any way of specifying this mapping?

I can do it by ignoring the `User` property and doing a manual join on `IQueryable` like this:

```
_dbContext.Foo
          .Join(_db.Users,
                kf => kf.UserId,
                u => u.SID, 
                (foo, user) => new Foo { User = user })
```

But i'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work?

Comment: Also wondering, I'm in the same boat I think...

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Could you please provide the query that threw the SqlNullValueException.

Answer (score 1):

Revisited this, because it always helps to understand EF better when using it on a suboptimal data model, in this case a model without enforced integrity.

**TL;DR**
The bad news is that the exception can only be circumvented, not prevented. The good news is that still a lot is possible.

First, the good news.

Using EFC 8.0. Having these classes:

```cs
class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public int? SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With mapping:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasOne(x => x.User)
        .WithMany()
        .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.SID)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(u => u.ID).ValueGeneratedNever();
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.SID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.SID).ValueGeneratedNever();
}
```

And a keyless database model:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tests](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [SID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

It's perfectly fine to do queries like this (where `db` is a context instance):

```cs
db.Tests.Include(t => t.User)
```

Which translates as:

```sql
SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[Name], [t].[UserId], [u].[SID], [u].[Name]
FROM [Tests] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Users] AS [u] ON [t].[UserId] = [u].[SID]
```

(Note that `Test.User` is `null` when it has a non-existing `UserId` value. The left join makes this a forgiving query.)

We can do an update:

```cs
db.Users.First().Name = "aa";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Which translates as:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[SID], [u].[Name]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
...
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @p0
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [SID] = @p1;
```

Likewise, records can be deleted using EF. In other words, EF will allow most of the common CRUD actions.

But here's some bad news.

When there's a `User` record that has `SID` = `null` there's no way to run a standard LINQ query on a `DbSet<User>` whenever the result is going to include that record. The statement `db.Users.Load()` throws the infamous exception:

```
SqlNullValueException  
Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.  
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlBuffer.cs:line 424
   at lambda_method791(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Load[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Adding a filter, `db.Users.Where(u => u.SID != null).Load()` seems an obvious safeguard. Unfortunately, that doesn't help. The SQL statement doesn't even contain a `WHERE` clause. Why not?

Because `SID` is `User`'s key property and therefore EF assumes that it's `not null` in the database. EF can't load entities without proper identification (basically because the change tracker is an identity map) and it has no patience with legacy databases where things may be less than ideal. What I mean is that EF deems the condition `Where(u => u.SID != null)` redundant and just ignores it.

That means that you always have to tread carefully when querying data. A change of content today may break a query that ran yesterday. It's OK to query users by `ID`, but using unqualified queries like `First()` (as I did above) is dangerous. One day, the "first" record may have no `SID`.

Fortunately, EF can't ignore this `Where`:

```cs
db.Users.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.SID > 0).Load()
```

This might even be applied as a [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters). But, although it runs fine, it adds a touch of "magic" to the code that the next developer may not understand. Also, it may have adverse effects on the query plan.

Finally, sometimes you may have to resort to raw SQL. For example:

```cs
db.Users.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.SID is not null")
    .Where(u => EF.Functions.Like(u.Name, "%e%")
    .Load();
```