# How to make nullable relations DB first in EF Core 6?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

We are developing an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and Entity Framework Core 6 for an already existing database. We are using Entity Framework Core and Automapper for accessing the SQL Server database.

There is a nullable column in a table which can be the principal key of 2 relations. If the column is not null, everything works fine, but if the column is null, we get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

The related code snippets are the following

`SapDatabase.cs` (this is an extension for the file, generated by `scaffoldDbContext`)

```cs
namespace cool_sap_api.Models.sapDatabase
{
    public partial class SapDatabase : DbContext
    {
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //...
            modelBuilder.Entity<ORDR>()
                .HasMany<ODLN>(order => order.WebDeliveryNotes)
                .WithOne(deliveryNote => deliveryNote.WebOrder)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .HasForeignKey(dln =>  dln.U_MCP_WEB_ID)
                .HasPrincipalKey(rdr => rdr.U_MCP_WEB_ID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ORDR>()
                .HasMany<OINV>(order => order.WebInvoices)
                .WithOne(invoice => invoice.WebOrder)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .HasForeignKey(inv => inv.U_MCP_WEB_ID)
                .HasPrincipalKey(rdr => rdr.U_MCP_WEB_ID);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

`ORDR.cs` (generated)

```cs
namespace cool_sap_api.Models.sapDatabase
{
    public partial class ORDR
    {
        // ...
        public string? U_MCP_WEB_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ORDR.cs` (extension)

```cs
namespace cool_sap_api.Models.sapDatabase
{
    public partial class ORDR
    {
        // ...
        public virtual List<ODLN>? WebDeliveryNotes { get; set; }
        public virtual List<OINV>? WebInvoices { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ODLN.cs` (extension)

```cs
namespace cool_sap_api.Models.sapDatabase;

public partial class ODLN
{
    // ...
    public ORDR? WebOrder { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

`OINV.cs` (extension)

```cs
namespace cool_sap_api.Models.sapDatabase 
{
    public partial class OINV 
    {
        // ...
        public ORDR? WebOrder { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

We have tried to flip the relation the following way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ODLN>()
            .HasOne<ORDR>(deliveryNote => deliveryNote.WebOrder)
            .WithMany(order => order.WebDeliveryNotes)
            .HasForeignKey("U_MCP_WEB_ID")
            .HasPrincipalKey("U_MCP_WEB_ID")
            .IsRequired(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<OINV>()
            .HasOne<ORDR>(invoice => invoice.WebOrder)
            .WithMany(order => order.WebInvoices)
            .HasForeignKey("U_MCP_WEB_ID")
            .HasPrincipalKey("U_MCP_WEB_ID")
            .IsRequired(false);
```

The result was the same.

Comment: What is your database structure like? Perhaps you can try joining the IQueryable manually like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489807/ef-core-one-to-many-with-optional-principal-key).

Comment: Also, there seems to be a problem with your flip relationship. Are you sure it flipped successfully?

Comment: The relevant part of the DB structre looks like this:

create table dbo.ORDR(
    -- other fields removed to make script shorter
    U_MCP_WEB_ID        nvarchar(100)
)

create table dbo.ODLN(
    -- other fields removed to make script shorter
    U_MCP_WEB_ID        nvarchar(100)
)

create table dbo.OINV(
    -- other fields removed to make script shorter
    U_MCP_WEB_ID        nvarchar(100)
)

I am able to join the 3 tables, but i would like to avoid that, because the DTO that I am using for the response is rather complex.

Comment: This is the scheme of the exemple resonse:
https://pastebin.com/uk8qbMib